# 550 file unavailable error with FtpWebRequest class file upload. Works fine in FileZilla

Tags: c#, .net, ftp

I'm searched and found other questions on this but none have solved my issues. I'm trying to upload a file via FTP using sample MSDN code. I get the The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access) error on this line: ftpstream.Close();

```
    string inputfilepath = @"C:\DWF\test.txt";
    string ftpfilepath = "/abc/def/hij/klm/nop/test.txt";
    string ftphost = "my-ser-ver1:2121";
    //here correct hostname or IP of the ftp server to be given  

    string ftpfullpath = "ftp://" + ftphost + ftpfilepath;
    FtpWebRequest ftp = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(ftpfullpath);
    ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
    //userid and password for the ftp server to given  

    ftp.KeepAlive = true;
    ftp.UseBinary = true;

    ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
    FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(inputfilepath);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
    fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    fs.Close();
    Stream ftpstream = ftp.GetRequestStream();
    ftpstream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    ftpstream.Close();
```

I have double checked the URI for blank spaces and there are none. I am able to complete this task using filezilla with the same user login. There is no oddball default directory that is already part of my URI. One thing for sure is that I am connecting to a unix server so maybe there is a setting I am missing?

### Edit #1 (Added error log from System.Net)

```
System.Net Information: 0 : [7584] FtpControlStream#62182359 - Received response [220 Oracle Content Services FTP Server ready.]

System.Net Information: 0 : [7584] FtpControlStream#62182359 - Sending command [USER myuser]

System.Net Information: 0 : [7584] FtpControlStream#62182359 - Received response [331 Password required for myuser.]

System.Net Information: 0 : [7584] FtpControlStream#62182359 - Sending command [PASS ********]

System.Net Information: 0 : [7584] FtpControlStream#62182359 - Received response [230 Login successful.]

System.Net Information: 0 : [7584] FtpControlStream#62182359 - Sending command [OPTS utf8 on]

System.Net Information: 0 : [7584] FtpControlStream#62182359 - Received response [500 Command not supported: OPTS]

System.Net Information: 0 : [7584] FtpControlStream#62182359 - Sending command [PWD]

System.Net Information: 0 : [7584] FtpControlStream#62182359 - Received response [257 "/"]

System.Net Information: 0 : [7584] FtpControlStream#62182359 - Sending command [TYPE I]

System.Net Information: 0 : [7584] FtpControlStream#62182359 - Received response [200 TYPE set to I.]

System.Net Information: 0 : [7584] FtpControlStream#62182359 - Sending command [PASV]

System.Net Information: 0 : [7584] FtpControlStream#62182359 - Received response [227 Entering Passive Mode (10,8,9,50,77,53)]

System.Net Information: 0 : [7584] FtpControlStream#62182359 - Sending command [STOR abc/def/hij/klm/nop/test.txt]

System.Net Information: 0 : [7584] FtpControlStream#62182359 - Received response [150 Ok to send data.]

System.Net Verbose: 0 : [7584] Exiting FtpWebRequest#10964107::GetRequestStream() 

System.Net Information: 0 : [7584] FtpControlStream#62182359 - Received response [550 Access denied.]

System.Net Information: 0 : [7584] FtpWebRequest#10964107::(Releasing FTP connection#62182359.)
```

Comment: Are you traversing any proxies?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This did the trick. apparently the CWD command behavior changed in the move from .NET 3.5 to 4.0.

You have to first call the method in this link.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2134299

Comment: What if you're using powershell instead of C# and therefore copying and pasting that function isn't really doable?

Comment: Just threw an +1 your way. Had a recently upgraded application, that acted out on downloads, not on uploads..... However, after doing as instructed all is well...

Comment: @Steen I just added an answer for you that contains the PowerShell equivalent to the code from SteveCalPoly's KB find.

Comment: I called the method, but the line "Type methodInfoType = methodInfoField.FieldType;" throw a null pointer in my case...

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to tell without detailed information about the error, but it seems most likely that somewhere in your path there's a directory missing. One thing to try if you use any non-standard characters in your FTP file path is to use [HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlpathencode.aspx) on it prior to adding it to the Url.

To get detailed troubleshooting information, I add the following inside the configuration element of my application's .config file:

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
    <source name="System.Net">
      <listeners>
        <add name="TraceFile"/>
      </listeners>
    </source>
    <source name="System.Net.Sockets" maxdatasize="1024">
      <listeners>
        <add name="TraceFile"/>
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>
  <sharedListeners>
    <add name="TraceFile" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="System.Net.trace.log" traceOutputOptions="DateTime"/>
  </sharedListeners>
  <switches>
    <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose"/>
    <!--<add name="System.Net.Sockets" value="Verbose"/>-->
  </switches>
  <trace autoflush="true" />
</system.diagnostics>
```

Also, just for reference, here's the code I use for uploads:

```
    private static FtpWebRequest CreateFtpWebRequest(string ftpUrl, string userName, string password, bool useSsl, bool allowInvalidCertificate, bool useActiveFtp)
    {
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpUrl);
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);

        if (useSsl)
        {
            request.EnableSsl = true;

            if (allowInvalidCertificate)
            {
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ServicePointManager_ServerCertificateValidationCallback;
            }
            else
            {
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = null;
            }
        }

        request.UsePassive = !useActiveFtp;

        return request;
    }

    private static void UploadFileToServer(string ftpUrl, string userName, string password, bool useSsl, bool allowInvalidCertificate, bool useActiveFtp, string filePath)
    {
        FtpWebRequest request = CreateFtpWebRequest(ftpUrl, userName, password, useSsl, allowInvalidCertificate, useActiveFtp);

        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

        long bytesReceived = 0;
        long bytesSent = 0;

        using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        using (FileStream uploadFileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
        {
            // Note that this method call requires .NET 4.0 or higher. If using an earlier version it will need to be replaced.
            uploadFileStream.CopyTo(requestStream);
            bytesSent = uploadFileStream.Position;
        }

        using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            bytesReceived = response.ContentLength;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem just recently.  It just popped on code that I had been using for years.
It turned out that I had been working with a number of ftp sites and was sending the same files to all these ftp sites.  Well, when I went to some ftp sites, I was left at root, but at others, i was immediately put on a subdirectory.
Before this recent change I could use request stream and put the file directly on the subdirectly where I was put.  As of last week I needed to fully qualify the path.

Hope this helps someone.....

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for Steen and contains a PowerShell equivalent to the code in http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2134299 below. I don't have a system that has the non-compliant behavior to test against so you'll need to try it yourself.

```
function SetMethodRequiresCWD() {
    [Type] $requestType = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]
    [System.Reflection.FieldInfo] $methodInfoField = $requestType.GetField("m_MethodInfo", [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::NonPublic -bor [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::Instance)
    [Type] $methodInfoType = $methodInfoField.FieldType


    [System.Reflection.FieldInfo] $knownMethodsField = $methodInfoType.GetField("KnownMethodInfo", [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::Static -bor [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::NonPublic)
    [Array] $knownMethodsArray = [Array]$knownMethodsField.GetValue($null);

    [System.Reflection.FieldInfo] $flagsField = $methodInfoType.GetField("Flags", [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::NonPublic -bor [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::Instance)

    [int] $MustChangeWorkingDirectoryToPath = 0x100
    ForEach ($knownMethod In $knownMethodsArray) {
        [int] $flags = [int]$flagsField.GetValue($knownMethod)
        $flags = $flags -bor $MustChangeWorkingDirectoryToPath
        $flagsField.SetValue($knownMethod, $flags)
    }
}
```