# File Upload to AS400 using FtpWebRequest

Tags: c#, ftp, ibm-midrange, ftpwebrequest

I’m attempting to upload a file to AS400 using C#. The structure is:

```
ftp_server_ip_address/library/table
```

E.g.:

```
10.123.1.23/ABCD/XYZ
```

FileName : sample.txt

The AS400 table has same fields as my file layout. I am able to successfully upload file using FTP commands using PUT command as below.

```
ftp> open 10.123.1.23
ftp> username
ftp> password
ftp> cd ABCD
ftp> put c:/sample.txt ABCD/XYZ
```

I get a success message.

But when I try using `FtpWebRequest`, I get a `550 :” File unavailable or no access”` error message.

I’m not sure how to construct the URI. 
Currently, my code looks like

```
FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"ftp://110.123.1.23/ABCD” + file.Name);
```

Also, I'm unable to browse to the FTP folder using Internet Explorer or Windows Explorer. I get the same 550 error. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Which .NET version are you using?

Comment: It targets .Net 4.0 Client profile using VS2010 of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're constructing the URL a bit wrong, you're missing a `/` before the file name, should probably be like this;

```
FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = 
    (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"ftp://110.123.1.23/ABCD/” + file.Name);
```

You're also not storing in the same directory as your interactive example;

```
ftp> cd ABCD
ftp> put c:/sample.txt ABCD/XYZ
```

will store the file XYZ in the directory ABCD/ABCD, not just ABCD as in your URL example.

Thirdly, if you're using .NET 4.0 or higher, you may [be bitten by **this** changed behavior in how directories are sent to the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621755/550-file-unavailable-error-with-ftpwebrequest-class-file-upload-works-fine-in-f).

Comment: I modified the URL as
FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"ftp://110.123.1.23/ABCD/ABCD/” + file.Name);

Now i get 501 Specified object name too long, limit is 10 characters: ABCD/Sampl. I'm unable to reduce the length further as the library which i refer as "ABCD" here is 9 char in length. What can be done?

Comment: @DeepthiRao Check the "resolution" section of [this page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2134299) since it seems like you're being bitten by the new .NET4.0 FTP behavior.

Comment: I tried that. It did not help. Same 501 error. :( i missed the slash in my previous comment. Modified url looks like  FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"110.123.1.23/ABCD/ABCD/” + file.Name);

Comment: @DeepthiRao You're missing the ftp:// in your URL now, besides that I can't see a problem. How are you setting the login information?

Comment: This time i fat fingered it. I just realized my access to this folder was revoked and I was provided with a new folder. A combination of things worked. 1. I added the code block you suggested for the .net 4.0 bug 2. Removed the file.Name from the URL. Now my URL looks like FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = 
    (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"ftp://110.123.1.23/ABCD/XYZ”); Thanks a ton