# FTP Download, can see file but not download, possibly due to uri mapping issue

Tags: c#, .net, ftp

I have just upgraded an application from net 3.5 to 4.0

I read and transfer files using ftp. An everything is great except for one of the servers I connect to. That server is strange to begin with as I have to go back one directory and down into another:

"ftp.server.com" actually puts me in ftp.server.com/up, and I need to read from ftp.server.com/out

I get a filelist using this url:

```
ftp://ftp.server.com/%2fout
```

Web request is created this way:

```
var request = (FtpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.server.com/%2fout");
```

I get the filelist - no problem, so that method works for connecting to the directory, but when trying to read one of the files i now get an error.

I create that request this way:

```
 var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.server.com/%2fout/" + filename);
```

I have logged the URI of the request to be:

```
ftp://ftp.server.com//out/ORDER25260.xml_XL1014254ORDER25260_response.xml
```

I get this stacktrace:

```
The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access).   at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.CheckError()
   at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.SyncRequestCallback(Object obj)
   at System.IO.Stream.Close()
   at System.Net.ConnectionPool.Destroy(PooledStream pooledStream)
   at System.Net.ConnectionPool.PutConnection(PooledStream pooledStream, Object owningObject, Int32 creationTimeout, Boolean canReuse)
   at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.FinishRequestStage(RequestStage stage)
   at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.SyncRequestCallback(Object obj)
   at System.Net.CommandStream.Abort(Exception e)
   at System.Net.CommandStream.CheckContinuePipeline()
   at System.Net.FtpDataStream.System.Net.ICloseEx.CloseEx(CloseExState closeState)
   at System.Net.FtpDataStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.IO.Stream.Close()
   at CustomModules.CustomModules.SupplierFunctions.FtpMethods.GetFile(SynsamSupplierSetting setting, String filename, Boolean deleteAfterLoad) in D:\WORK\dynamicweb\Source\CustomModules\SupplierFunctions\FtpMethods.cs:line 295
```

I have noproblem downloading via FileZilla using same credentials

Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does that FTP work in Windows Explorer?

Comment: No it dosent - only filezilla - well, and partly in my code :-)

Comment: I have requested the owner of the server to let me in at root-level to avoid the go-one-back, go-one-down, but apparently that is not an option

Comment: I have had this many time with customers that need to use my FTP.  Try changing the Passive FTP setting and HTTP proxy setting in IE.   This IE setting also effects Windows Explorer but not FileZilla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this using information on this thread:

[550 file unavailable error with FtpWebRequest class file upload. Works fine in FileZilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621755/550-file-unavailable-error-with-ftpwebrequest-class-file-upload-works-fine-in-f)

User SteveCalPoly writes:

> apparently the CWD command behavior changed in the move from .NET 3.5
>   to 4.0.
>
> You have to first call the method in this link.
>
> http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2134299

The question relates to uploads, so I missed it in my first google for answers